# Unspecific CORS error with Post method using fetch on React (Spring Boot backend)

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, fetch, http-status-code-403

Very new to React coming from a decent understanding of Angular. I have had CORS issues with Angular and have always solved them with backend config. Unfortunately that has not been the case so far with React.

Also, quick note that this is app purely for educational purposes and no actual sensitive date is being submitted or stored in the database. My main concern is with just getting this thing working rather than flawless security, as I am still pretty basic in my React knowledge.

The issue comes with posting to my API using fetch in React. The post method works just fine in Postman, but when using the browser (Chrome) I get the following message:

```
POST https://bookkeeperdb.herokuapp.com/api/books/add net::ERR_ABORTED 403

Response {type: "cors", url: "https://bookkeeperdb.herokuapp.com/api/books/add", redirected: false, status: 403, ok: false, …}
body: (...)
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {}
ok: false
redirected: false
status: 403
statusText: ""
type: "cors"
url: "https://bookkeeperdb.herokuapp.com/api/books/add"
__proto__: Response
```

Initially, I was getting more informational errors about being more specific in my config rather than using the wildcard for everything. All of my research into this issue has bounced me from one error to the next and has made the CORS config on my backend more specific. However, I am stuck at this issue and cannot find any relevant solutions to this problem online.

Here is my code for reference:
FRONTEND (form submission in REACT):

```
handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const formFields = {
        title: this.state.bookTitle,
        synopsis: this.state.synopsisInput,
        pageCount: parseInt(this.state.pageCountInput),
        isbn: parseInt(this.state.isbnInput),
        genre_name: this.state.genreInput,
        author_first_name: 'Cormac',
        author_last_name: 'McCarthy',
        // author_first_name: this.state.authorInput.slice(0, this.state.authorInput.indexOf(" ")),
        // author_last_name: this.state.authorInput.slice(this.state.authorInput.indexOf("")),
        publisher_name: this.state.publisherInput
    }
    const headers = new Headers({
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.token}`
    })
    console.log(`The following title was submitted: ${formFields.title}`);
    fetch("https://bookkeeperdb.herokuapp.com/api/books/add", {
        method: 'POST',
        credentials: "include",
        headers: headers,
        body: JSON.stringify(formFields)
    })
        .then((response) => console.log(response))
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
}
```

BACKEND (corsconfig in SPRING BOOT):

```
    @Configuration
public class CorsConfig {
    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer(){
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry){
                registry.addMapping("/**")
                        .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS")
                        .allowedHeaders("*")
                        .allowCredentials(true)
                        .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000",
                                "http://localhost:3000/contribute");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, really just took some experimenting but turns out including 'Bearer' in my Authorization header was messing up my token authentication when submitting the post. Well that was anti-climatic.